# Create drop shadow effects in Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

The border shadow effects used in the images of this [blog post](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css3-regions.html) seem to be embeded in the images themselves (not css3).  How can it be created in imagemagick?

**Edit 1:**
The solution which I found quite accidentlly is posted below as an answer.

Comment: What specific image from that post are you looking to create in imagemagick?

Comment: All images within the article, the ones given as illustrations.

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific about what you want to get any answers.  What do you have as input, what exactly do you want as output.  Pull out the specific parts of the article you are interested in duplicating and the exact picture -- there are lots in there that are all different and we have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I have not specified which effects I am looking for. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `-shadow` argument on `convert` that has options to do this.

http://web.archive.org/web/20120607055659/http://blog.bemoko.com/2009/07/01/add-shadow-and-border-to-images-with-imagemagick/

Answer (score 16):

Somehow I found the command which does what I wanted exactly:

[image: Image with white border and dropshadow]

For images which are already scaled and compressed:

```
 convert input.jpeg -bordercolor white -border 13 \( +clone -background black -shadow 80x3+2+2 \) +swap -background white -layers merge +repage output.jpg
```

For creating thumbnails:

```
 convert input.jpeg -thumbnail 200x200 -bordercolor white -border 6 \( +clone -background black -shadow 80x3+2+2 \) +swap -background white -layers merge +repage  output.jpg
```

For raw images:

```
convert input.jpeg -scale 600x400 -quality 86 -strip -bordercolor white -border 13 \( +clone -background black -shadow 80x3+2+2 \) +swap -background white -layers merge +repage output.jpg
```

Comment: -background none transparent_bg.png

Answer (score 1):

Shutter uses the following command https://github.com/shutter-project/shutter/blob/master/share/shutter/resources/system/plugins/perl/spshadow/spshadow#L375

```
convert in.png -gravity 'northwest' -background 'rgba(255,255,255,0)' -splice '10x10' \( +clone -background '#005f005f005f0000' -shadow "80x3-1-1" \) +swap -background none -mosaic +repage \( +clone -background '#005f005f005f0000' -shadow "80x3+5+5" \) +swap -background none -mosaic +repage out.png
```