# Combining images in ImageMagick with drop shadow

Tags: image, shadow, graphicsmagick

I am cropping and blurring a 960x960px image to 960x416 using GraphicsMagick:

> gm convert -resize 960x416^ -gravity center -crop 960x416+0+0 +repage in.jpg bg.png
>
> gm mogrify -gaussian 25x10 bg.png

After that, I create a 200x200px thumbnail of same initial image:

> gm convert -resize 200x200 in.jpg top.png

On the last step, I combine both images, where the thumbnail will be placed on the top left position of the background image:

> gm composite top.png bg.png -geometry 960x416+50+16 out.jpg

This works like a charm. But what I now need is a automatically generated dropshadow for the image top.png when it will be composited on the top of the bg.png in the last step. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe the answers here can help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351828/create-drop-shadow-effects-in-imagemagick

Comment: Thank you, I already had a look at this, but I could not figure out how to do this with GraphicsMagick.